# Kettle: 400 Error in RESTful API call

Tags: json, rest, pentaho, kettle, http-status-code-400

I've got a process which has 7 threads, two of which pull data from a custom-made rest application. I'm using the REST client to pull after getting a token using basic authentication. [image: transformation]

Here is the transformation that does all this.

Unfortunately, It only runs in Spoon. I can run the entire parent process in Spoon and get a valid result, however when I tried to automate it by calling Kitchen from a batch script, instead of getting my valid data I get a 400 error saying I have an invalid hostname. I can tell from the logs that I'm using the correct url and even am getting a valid token, however the resulting data is just the 400 error. And this only occurs outside of Spoon, regardless of what permissions I run this under.

This seems like a bug in Kettle, and I'm pursuing a workaround, however any advice is welcome

UPDATE 1: We've established with the recepient server owner that they are not receiving the requests in their IIS logs, so something on our side is killing the requests. Is there a difference in permission levels between kitchen and spoon? We're running both at highest permissions as the admin but still seeing the difference

Comment: How host name passed to "Rest Client" Step in field or variable? It is common mistake to use variable in jvm context or variable defined in Spoon but not in job. Anyway use very simple debug tool "Write Log" step and place it before Rest Client step.

Comment: The url is passed in as a parameter from the parent job's call to the transformation. And in the log I can see that it is using the correct url when it notes that it had a 136 millisecond delay before getting it's response from that url:

2015/09/29 23:20:16 - REST Get Data.0 - Response time (milliseconds): [134] for [https://valid.url.location?programcode=set]

Comment: I don't like strategy to pass parameters from job to transformation. It leads to error between Spoon and kitchen. Common mistake to set transformation parameter and in testing purpose assign default value to it. While u  use Spoon everything seem to be 'OK' but, then u use same job in kitchen it will always use default param despite value u pass from job and it looks like it works but u get wrong data.

Comment: but even with that, I also have the value set in the default as well because I've been doing so much testing, and we still get the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tracked it down to a difference in version. The batch file was calling an older version of Kettle while Spoon was using a newer version that corrected this bug

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting a GET method to retrieve the data from your api try to use a **HTTP client step** instead the REST step.

Other option is double check the settings on your Rest client step. I dont think is a bug, i use this step often.

error 400 means bad request, so thats what are you doing: a bad request not expected from your api.

Comment: I'll test using the http client, with the get method, however I think I tested this. Also it's not even hitting the API, we had the owner check their iss logs and they're not seeing the requests made via kitchen or pan

Comment: Running the same request through http client changes nothing, same 400 error